# asp.net ext.net show file in browser new window

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, ext.net

Our asp.net application uses EXT.NET.
When a "View" menu is clicked, an EXT.NET window shows up with a content of a PDF file.
The problem is we can't drag and drop that window to a body of an Outlook email (to make it as the email attachment).

I am thinking one of the way to drag and drop to a body of an Outlook email is to show the PDF file in the browser window, not an EXT.NET window. How can I do that ?
Thank you.

This is from the View (Index.cshtml):

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Archive";
var X = Html.X();
}

@section SPAViews {
@(
X.Viewport().Layout(LayoutType.Fit).Items(
X.TabPanel().ID("ArchiveTabPanel")
.Items(
        X.GridPanel().ID("GridPanel1").MarginSpec("1 1 1 1").Cls("cust-grid").Title("Archive").Icon(Icon.ServerCompressed)
        .Plugins(X.GridFilters())
        .View(Html.X().GridView().StripeRows(true).TrackOver(false))
        .SelectionModel(X.CheckboxSelectionModel().Mode(SelectionMode.Multi))
        .TopBar(
            X.Toolbar().MinHeight(35)
                .Items(
            :
                            , X.Button()
                                    .Text("View")
                                    .Icon(Icon.PageWhiteAcrobat)
                                        .DirectEvents(de =>
                                        {
                                            de.Click.Action = "Submit";
                                            de.Click.EventMask.ShowMask = true;
                                            de.Click.Method = HttpMethod.POST;
                                            de.Click.ExtraParams.Add(new Parameter()
                                            {
                                                Name = "selection",
                                                Value = "getselection()",
                                                Mode = ParameterMode.Raw
                                            });
                                            de.Click.Timeout = 360000;
                                        })
```

This is from ArchiveController.cs:

```
    public ActionResult Submit(string selection)
    {
            int cnt = SetTempData(selection);
            RenderWindows(String.Format("View Archive {0}.",cnt),0,cnt);
            return this.Direct();
   }

    [ChildActionOnly]
    public void RenderWindows(string title,int download,int cnt)
    {
        Window win = new Window
        {
            ID = "Windows1",
            Title = title,
            Icon = Ext.Net.Icon.PageWhiteAcrobat,
            Height = download == 1 ? 150 : 600,
            Width = download == 1 ? 400 : 800,
            BodyPadding = 2,
            Modal = true,
            Layout = "Fit",
            CloseAction = CloseAction.Destroy,
            Loader = new ComponentLoader()
            {
                Url = Url.Action("ArcTicket", "Archive"),
                Mode = LoadMode.Frame,
                DisableCaching = true,
                ShowWarningOnFailure = true,
                LoadMask = { ShowMask = true, Msg = String.Format("Generating {0} pdf ...",cnt) }
            },
            Buttons = {
                new Button(){ Text="Close & Clear", Icon=Ext.Net.Icon.TableRowDelete, Handler="App.GridPanel1.selModel.deselectAll();App.Windows1.close();"},
                new Button(){ Text="Close", Icon=Ext.Net.Icon.Cancel, Handler="App.Windows1.close();"}
                    }
        };
        win.Loader.Params.Add(new Parameter() { Name = "download", Value = download.ToString(), Mode = ParameterMode.Value });
        win.Render(RenderMode.Auto);
    }

    public FileStreamResult ArcTicket(int download)
    {
        String id = TempData["xid"].ToString();
        TempData.Remove("xid");
        String ticket = Uow.TICKETs.GetXmlBatch(id);

        Byte[] pdf = MvcApplication.Fop.Write(enumFobFormat.Pdf
                            , ticket
                            , Server.MapPath("/Resources/xslt/Ticket.xsl")
                            );

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(pdf);
        FileStreamResult fs = new FileStreamResult(ms, "application/pdf");
        if (download == 1)
            fs.FileDownloadName = string.Format("Archive_{0:yyyyMMdd_HHmmss}.pdf", DateTime.Now);

        return fs;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make normal button / link with `href` to `ArcTicket` action with `target="_blank"` then it will be opened in new tab

Update:

Change .TopBar to something like this. Option 1 may be problematic because of dynamic parameter from grid and i am not sure it will be possible to pass it there

Option 1:

```
.TopBar(
            X.Toolbar().MinHeight(35)
                .Items(
            :
                            , X.Button()
                                    .Text("View")
                                    .Icon(Icon.PageWhiteAcrobat)
                                    .Href(Url.Action("ArcTicket", "Archive"))
                                    .HrefTarget("blank")
                                    .BaseParams("yourparameters")
```

Option 2

```
.TopBar(
            X.Toolbar().MinHeight(35)
                .Items(
            :
                            , X.Button()
                                    .Text("View")
                                    .Icon(Icon.PageWhiteAcrobat)
                                    .Handler("YourJSFUnctionWithWIndowOpen")
```

Comment: Thank you. How can I do that ? 
Did you mean in this section ?
 {
                Url = Url.Action("ArcTicket", "Archive"),
                Mode = LoadMode.Frame,
                DisableCaching = true,
                ShowWarningOnFailure = true,
                LoadMask = { ShowMask = true, Msg = String.Format("Generating {0} pdf ...",cnt) }
            },

Comment: When I add new { target = "_blank" } in the Url.Action, it still shows in the EXT.NET window, not in a new browser tab/window:

Url = Url.Action("ArcTradeTicket", "Archive", new { target = "_blank" }),
                    Mode = LoadMode.Frame,
                    DisableCaching = true,
                    ShowWarningOnFailure = true,
                    LoadMask = { ShowMask = true, Msg = String.Format("Generating {0} pdf Trade Ticket...",cnt) }

Comment: no i meant to remove window and instead TopBar `X.Button` `Ext.DirectEvent` make normal button link with target `_blank.`

Comment: i looked in docs and for `Button` there is property `Href` here goes your link `HrefTarget` here goes `_blank`. `BaseParams` here goes additional parameters. Eventualy if does not work you can create JS onclick handler and there you can make `window.open()` or something like that

Comment: Did you mean do this in the View ? What did you mean by "to remove window" ? What did you mean by "instead TopBar X.Button Ext.DirectEvent make normal button link " ? Did you mean add normal button outside the .TopBar X.Button() add a normal button href link ?

Comment: Did you mean outside the .TopBar X.Button() add normal href button like <a href="Url.Action("' arcticket', new {download=ViewBag.Download})' target='_blank'>Download</a> ? 
Do I put that inside the @section SPAViews ?

Comment: i udpdated my answer with example Second will for sure work becaus in JS function i can do almost anything but it can be less readable than first option which i am not sure

Comment: On the View, I added ,X.Button().Text("Testing").Icon(Icon.PageWhiteAcrobat).Handler("Test();") and a JS function var Test = function() {
  return window.open("http://myWebsite/myFile.pdf");
}. 
Is that what you meant ? When I click on the "Testing" button, I am able to open myFile.pdf on a different browser window, but when I drag and drop that file from the browser (IE) to the body of an Outlook email, instead of making the file as attachment, it writes this to the body of the email: http://myWebsite/myFile.pdf.
Note: there is an HTTP:// before myWebsite(the editor deletes it)

Comment: i am not sure if drag drop works from opened window/ tab with pdf. I just told you how to open pdf in new tab/window

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: if this is answer to your question mark it respectively